# Redirect to specific vue component from external website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect

I'm trying to get a link from one website, to a specific component in another external website. The external website is utilizing `vue` and `vue-router`.

Assume that the first site is running on `localhost:3000`, I want to redirect to `localhost/#/payments`.

When I try direct redirect using this snippet(in `localhost:3000`):

```
<script>
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/#/payments";
</script>
```

Vue is opening the default component, which is not desired.

EDIT:
This is the router of localhost:

```
export default function paymentRoutes() {
    return [
        {
            path: "/payment/",
            name: "PaymentSuccess",
            component: PaymentSuccess
        }
    ]
}
```

then in separated file:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [ ...paymentRoutes()]
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: probably need to see target site's router

Comment: @JayLi Added the router configuration

Comment: It depends on the router mode - hash or history, and also on the path of the route: the router config specifies `/payment/` but you're redirecting to `/payments`. These should match literally.

Comment: The issue was that the vue application was always pushing to the default route(which was /products).